# Newbie trying to scrape site with no luck

Tags: php, curl, dom, web-scraping

I am very new to php and have tried a couple of things to try and scrape 1 of 2 sites. Either of these site would be ok for the data I am looking for.
Tried to figure out how to do this using youtube videos and other resources. 
it could be that this is far to complicated for me to understand.  use CURL, DOM etc, but are struggling to get me head around it. 
I am only wanting to return DATE&Time, race Course and racehorse name.

I wondered if someone can help to to explain where to look, or what code to use. or even where I am going wrong. 
I will be integrating this code into a wordpress page in a table format

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$html=file_get_html("https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/profiles/trainer/216");
//$html=file_get_html("https://www.racingpost.com/profile/trainer/28787/richard-hannon/entries");

$row_count=0;
$json = array();

// Find all links 
$table = $html->find('table', 0);
foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
$day = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
$horse = $row->find('td',1)->innertext;
$racecourse = $row->find('td',2)->innertext;

$json[] = [ 'Date & Time' => strip_tags($day), 'Horse' => strip_tags($horse),'Racecourse' => strip_tags($racecourse)];
}

$options = array(
'http' => array(
'method'  => 'POST',
'content' => json_encode(array('Closings' =>$json)),
'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
            "Accept: application/json\r\n"
)
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
$response = json_decode( $result );

echo json_encode(array('Closings' =>$json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);  


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another method replace for file_get_html.
I suggest that you should use this package: https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

More details:

```
$url = 'https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/profiles/trainer/216';
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->get($url);
$data = $curl->response;
$curl->close();
$html = str_get_html($data);
foreach($html->find('a[class="person-profile-racing-form-racecard-link"]') as $e){      
    $date = $e->innertext;  
    echo $date.'</br>';     
};
$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

:) Good luck

Comment: That has completely blown my mind :-( I have no idea where to start

Comment: @dave Check my comment

Comment: Thanks, but I get a 500 server error when I try and run the code, Sorry as I said I have no idea really :-(

Comment: Thankyou very much for the continued support however I am Sorry to say that the code still does not work - Server error 500

Comment: I have tested that code on my computer, it's work. What is your errors mess?

Comment: This page isn’t working hammie07.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
<?php
$url = 'https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/profiles/trainer/216';
$curl = new Curl();
$curl->get($url);
$data = $curl->response;
$curl->close();
$html = str_get_html($data);
foreach($html->find('a[class="person-profile-racing-form-racecard-link"]') as $e){      
    $date = $e->innertext;  
    echo $date.'</br>';     
};
$html->clear();
unset($html);
?>

Comment: I copied and pasted the p above. the link is http://hammie07.com/scrape/index6.php

Comment: @dave Please show all errors. Add this line to top of your code

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Curl' not found in /home/davidhammon/hammie07.com/index6.php on line 4

Comment: Please read how to setup from here https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class